# ng-disable tab/button when content in previous tab has not completed

Tags: angularjs, tabs

I make a tab panel and declare it as form type, then i put validation ng-disabled in button& tab. i want the button available after i finish fill up two form,my button is disabled at first but when i finish fill up "first" form then it able to clicked.  And also tab, it never disabled...

```
   <div class="panel-body">
       <form class="tab-content form-horizontal"name="formData" novalidate>
                <div id="form-views" ui-view></div>
       </form>
```

here my code:

button

```
    <button type="button" ng-click="addPost()"                    
      ngdisabled="formData.$invalid" class="btn btn-success">Submit
    </button>
```

tab

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
            <div class="panel panel-tab rounded shadow">
                <div class="panel-heading1 no-padding">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-pills">
                        <li class="active"  ui-sref=".personal" >
                            <a data-toggle="tab">
                                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                                <div>
                                    <span class="text-strong">Step 1</span>
                                    <span>Personal</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".test" ng-disabled="formData.$invalid"> 
                            <a data-toggle="tab" >
                                <i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>
                                <div >
                                    <span class="text-strong">Step 2</span>
                                    <span>Test Date</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="" ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".testDetail">
                            <a data-toggle="tab" >
                                <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
                                <div>
                                    <span class="text-strong">Step 3</span>
                                    <span>Test Details</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-sub-heading">
                    <div class="inner-all">
                        <progressbar class="progress-striped active no-margin progress-xs" value='20' max="100" type="success"><i></i></progressbar>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="tab-content form-horizontal" name="formData"novalidate>
                        <div id="form-views" ui-view></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

this is my "personal details" tab

```
<div class="tab-pane  inner-all" id="tab3-1">
<h4 class="page-header">Personal</h4>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6"  ng-class="{ 'has-error' : formData.name.$invalid && !formData.name.$pristine }">
        <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" ng-model="formData.ngCandName" required>
        <p ng-show="formData.name.$invalid && !formData.name.$pristine" class="help-block">Candidate name is required.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group"  ng-class="{ 'has-error' : formData.background.$invalid && !formData.background.$pristine }">
    <label class="col-sm-2">University</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control" name="background" placeholder="Background" ng-model="formData.ngCandBackg" required>
         <p ng-show="formData.background.$invalid && !formData.background.$pristine" class="help-block">Candidate background is required.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group mb-0" >
    <label class="col-sm-2">Gender</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6" >
        <div class="rdio rdio-theme inline mr-10">
            <input type="radio" id="male3"  ng-model="formData.gender" name="radio"  value="male" required >
            <label for="male3">Male</label>
        </div>
        <div class="rdio rdio-theme inline">
            <input type="radio" id="female3" name="radio" ng-model="formData.gender"  value="female" required>
            <label for="female3">Female</label>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : formData.tel.$invalid && !formData.tel.$pristine }">
    <label class="col-sm-2" >Telephone number</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="number"   ng-maxlength="11" class="form-control" name="tel" placeholder="Telephone number" ng-model="formData.ngCandTel" required>
         <p ng-show="((formData.tel.$invalid && !formData.tel.$pristine))" class="help-block">Please insert telephone number.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : formData.Email.$invalid && !formData.Email.$pristine }">
    <label class="col-sm-2">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="Email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="formData.ngCandEmail" required>
         <p ng-show="formData.Email.$error.email" class="help-block">Candidate Email is invalid.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Haven't looked at your code too in depth, but try using ng-disabled instead of ngdisabled. Not sure if its a typo. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Comment: @chung neng NG Where is a your input field ??? Input field required="" or  required='true'.

Comment: @NetSonu edit ard....my input field is there

Comment: Paste your running plunkr or jsfiddle bcoz your code is not write proper way.